# Stop loop creating un-wanted code?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

When I run my code, I get the following output:

```
<Placemark>
            <description>Picture<![CDATA[<img src='./files/picOne.jpg' width='400' height='300'>]]></description>
        <styleUrl>#Photo</styleUrl>
        <coordinates>-1.57245646667, 53.8090789556</coordinates>
</Placemark>

        <styleUrl>#Photo</styleUrl>
        <coordinates>-1.56958587633, 53.8345916667</coordinates>
</Placemark>



<Placemark>
            <description>Picture<![CDATA[<img src='./files/picTwo.jpg' width='400' height='300'>]]></description>
        <styleUrl>#Photo</styleUrl>
        <coordinates>-1.57245646667, 53.8090789556</coordinates>
</Placemark>

        <styleUrl>#Photo</styleUrl>
        <coordinates>-1.56958333333, 53.8111916667</coordinates>
</Placemark>


        </Folder>
        </Document>
        </kml>
```

I want the following output in the txt file:

```
<Placemark>
            <description>Picture<![CDATA[<img src='./files/picOne.jpg' width='400' height='300'>]]></description>
        <styleUrl>#Photo</styleUrl>
        <coordinates>-1.57245646667, 53.8090789556</coordinates>
</Placemark>


<Placemark>
            <description>Picture<![CDATA[<img src='./files/picTwo.jpg' width='400' height='300'>]]></description>
        <styleUrl>#Photo</styleUrl>
        <coordinates>-1.57245646667, 53.8090789556</coordinates>
</Placemark>
```

I don't know why my script is generating this extra bit of code after each loop.

```
        **<styleUrl>#Photo</styleUrl>
        <coordinates>-1.57245646667, 53.8111916667</coordinates>
</Placemark>**
```

Here is the code:

```
oneLat = ['53.8290433456','53.8346016367']
oneLong = ['-1.57245646667', '1.56959975983']
picList = ['picOne.jpg', 'picTwo.jpg']

coordPairs = zip((-float(x) for x in oneLong), (float(x) for x in oneLat))

with open("temp.txt",'w') as f:
    increment = 0
    while increment < len(picList):
        f.write("\n\n<Placemark>\n")
        f.write("\t\t\t<description>Picture<![CDATA[<img src='./files/{}' width='400' height='300'>]]></description>\n".format(picList[increment]))
        increment = increment + 1
        for coord in coordPairs:
            f.write("\t\t<styleUrl>#Photo</styleUrl>\n")
            f.write("\t\t<coordinates>{}, {}</coordinates>\n".format(*coord))
            f.write("</Placemark>\n\n")

    f.write('''
        </Folder>
        </Document>
        </kml>''')
```

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated

Comment: Well yes - but I don't want it to generate that code. I'm asking how I can make it do what I want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does exactly what instructed. For each coordinate pair, you output that section. Just remove it if you don’t want it. Realistically, I think you just want to change the indentation of the code generating the closing tag:

```
for coord in coordPairs:
    f.write("\t\t<styleUrl>#Photo</styleUrl>\n")
    f.write("\t\t<coordinates>{}, {}</coordinates>\n".format(*coord))

f.write("</Placemark>\n\n")
```

However, I advise you to use a proper XML generator instead, that way such errors are fundamentally avoidable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment- I completely misread what the question was asking.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. I thought it would be the indentation. Will select as correct answer soon as it lets me.